# Read JSON file using PYTHON and create an excel file with that data

Tags: python, json, excel

I am working on a project where i have to read a JSON file and then load the data in an excel file. Not sure how to go about this in Python and i need some real help. 
Here is the JSON structure:

```
{"Models":[{"name":"AAA", "text":"some text", "structure":[{"column":"zzz", "type":"string"}, .....]}, {"name":"BBB", "text":"some text", "structure":[{"column":"zzz", "type":"string"}, .....]}]}
```

I need to convert this in the following excel format:
**Name| Column | Type**
AAA | zzz    | string
BBB | yyy    | text
CCC | xxx    | string

Not sure how to do this as Column and Type are under a different key and Name is different key.

Answer (score 0):

Load json file as dict and iterate through it

```
import json

f = open("f.json")
data = json.load(f)
f.close()
for x in data.get('Models'):
    name = x.get('name')
    for s in x.get('structure'):
        #write this string to a csv file
        print(name + ' ' + s.get('column') + ' ' + s.get('type'))
```

Comment: This works! thank you so much. Appreciate the help very much.

Comment: In the code above, I can see the data printed in the console. How do i print this to an excel file? Could you help me in that?